# Accessing lock comment on pre-lock hook

Tags: svn, locking, hook

I want my programmers to always put a message when locking a file in their working copy (i.e. `svn lock tree.jpg -m "reason for locking"`)
Is there a way for the pre-lock hook to know if a message was place and what it was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `hooks/pre-lock.tmpl` in your repository. In my case it contains the following info, indicating that the lock comment is the 4'th parameter:

```
# PRE-LOCK HOOK
#
# The pre-lock hook is invoked before an exclusive lock is
# created.  Subversion runs this hook by invoking a program
# (script, executable, binary, etc.) named 'pre-lock' (for which
# this file is a template), with the following ordered arguments:
#
#   [1] REPOS-PATH   (the path to this repository)
#   [2] PATH         (the path in the repository about to be locked)
#   [3] USER         (the user creating the lock)
#   [4] COMMENT      (the comment of the lock)
#   [5] STEAL-LOCK   (1 if the user is trying to steal the lock, else 0)

...
```

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks!  I was using as reference the second edition of Version Control with Subversion from O'Reilly, and it only shows the first three parameters.  I guess this is pretty new.